# What does the error line prefix `W: ` mean, like from apt-get or other, similar command's?

Tags: apt, error-handling

**It seem common knowledge that this is a warning message, but is this accurate?**

And if so, then where is it documented?  (I've already searched the man pages for dpkg and apt-get and the web.  I also tried adding `--quiet`, and `--quiet --quiet` options, but they don't seem to silence these `W: ...` lines.)

---

**Also is this only true for apt-get, or is it more widely true**, like via some standard c library or some historical standard?

---

For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get source somepackage
...
W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file ...
```

---

**Also, are their other standard or similar, error line prefix codes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt` (the program and the software collection that `apt-get` is part of) uses three different prefixes to distinguish the type or level of diagnostic messages:

1. `E` is for errors. An error stops the program from being able to continue operation.  The program will typically terminate upon errors. A typical error message from `apt` is `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`.
2. `W` is for warnings. A warning is something that is abnormal, but that doesn't stop the program from continuing to operate. A typical warning message from `apt` is `W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`.
3. `N` is for notices. A notice is something that the program wants you to be aware of but that is not a warning. A typical notice from `apt` is `N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it`.

It is conventional to refer to a diagnostic message that terminates the processing as "an error message" and to refer to a diagnostic message that does not terminate the processing as "a warning message". However, the way these are presented to the user may differ between tools.

The common `syslogd` logging daemon on Unix systems divide *logging messages* into the severity levels `emerg`, `alert`, `crit`, `err`,
`warning`, `notice`, `info` and `debug` (in decreasing order of severity), and even though the `syslogd` service is usually only used by system services and daemon processes, I'm assuming that the `apt` developer(s) have borrowed the `N` ("notice") prefix from this division.

These levels of severity of log messages *are* standard, as in they are defined for logging using [the `syslog()` system interface in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html). The way `apt` prefixes its diagnostic messages with a severity prefix is not something I've seen very often. However, seeing the words "warning" and "error" is common in diagnostic output from compilers.

The `--quiet` option for `apt-get` makes the program's *ordinary* (non-diagnostic) output terser.  This works similarly to similar options for other commands, and it's uncommon that a program disables diagnostic output through options.